# Python : call ffmpeg command line with subprocess

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to call simple ffmpeg command line with subprocess.call.
(Example : `ffmpeg -i input\video.mp4 -r 30 input\video.avi`)

By typing directly the ffmpeg command it works, but when I try to call it with subprocess.call : `subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i input\video.mp4 -r 30 input\video.avi', shell=True)` there is no error, but it doesn't produce anything.

Any idea where can be the problem?
(I'm working with python 3.4 or 2.7, I tried both)

Comment: unrelated: you don't need `shell=True` on Windows here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the problem : when you are using subprocess you MUST use

```
/
```

for your files location instead of

```
\
```

**EDIT** : or you can use  raw-string literals -> `r'ffmpeg -i input\video.mp4 ...'` (notice: r'') or you can double them '`\\`' 
  *Thanks to J.F. Sebastian*

Comment: There is *nothing* special about subprocess. You could use raw-string literals for Windows paths that contain backslashes e.g., `r'ffmpeg -i input\video.mp4 ...'` (notice: `r''`) or you should double them `'\\'`

Answer (score 0):

```
x=subprocess.Popen('ffmpeg -i input\video.mp4 -r 30 input\video.avi', shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output,err=x.communicate()
if output:
      print "success ",output
else:
      print "error ",err
```

You can try this and check output and errors if any.

Comment: With the updated code I have : error b'' (I changed error to err, error wasn't defined)

Comment: @Jacqueslelezard your `ffmpeg` command is not working properly.It is failing with error `b`.

Comment: I see that, but why? If I type exactly the same command without running it from python there is no any problem...

Comment: @Jacqueslelezard have you checked the file location?is the script located at correct location?